# Is it better to use || or include? when checking a variable against multiple values?

Tags: ruby

Which way of writing this condition is better?

1)

```
(self.expense_gl_dist_code.dist_type == GlDistCode::PERCENTAGE || self.expense_gl_dist_code.dist_type == GlDistCode::MIXED)
```

2)

```
["GlDistCode::PERCENTAGE","GlDistCode::MIXED"].include?(self.expense_gl_dist_code.dist_type)
```

Comment: This is (at least) the third question you've written here with the same title, please try to make the titles of your questions more representative of what you're asking.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis Sorry for that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the second clearer for two reasons:

1) In the second version the elements being checked for are all next to each other, separated by commas. In the first version there's always `self.expense_gl_dist_code.dist_type ==`, so it's less easy to scan them all at once.

2) In the second version it's immediately obvious that all elements are checked for the same condition, while in the first version it could say something like

```
dist_type == GlDistCode::PERCENTAGE || dist_type == GlDistCode::MIXED || dist_type != GlDistCode::WHATEVER
```

and you might not notice right away.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is much clearer and therefore to be preferred to the slightly obfuscated second option.

Comment: Is it really? Given that the variable access string is long, I would think this breaks down if you have more conditions-- yes, the first one is more readable at this point, but imagine having to check for 10 different possibilities like that. The `Array.include?` method is a little less clear initially, but once you figure out how the sense of the test is sort of reversed it's no problem.

Comment: perhaps a switch statement would be more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just comparing two elements, I'd say either is fine.

I'm more inclined to the second version, because you can then include all the elements you want to validate against into a single variable, and name it. For example

```
ALLOWED_TYPES = [GldDistCode::PERCENTAGE, GlDistCode::MIXED]
```

then

```
if ALLOWED_TYPES.include?(dist_type)
```

is more legible IMHO.

BTW, you're using strings (`"GldDistCode::PERCENTAGE"`) instead of the actual value which you intended.